# File location for CSV file

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a string and I keep getting errors trying to place the location to save the file.  I need all the security logs to be saved at C:\logs but it keeps failing when I try to place it somewhere

```
Export-Csv ('security-log-{0}.csv' -f ([DateTime]::Now).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))
```

Comment: Please include the actual error / specific problem you are getting when asking questions.

Comment: What is the full error you're getting?  The answer provided below, may be a solution, or may not, depending on your error.

Comment: I apologize, the issue is wants it runs, I dont know where it is going and I need it to save in a specific place.  Joey thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

»It keeps failing« is less than helpful as a problem description. However, if you require the logs to be saved in a specific folder it would help to include that folder in the path you're writing to:

```
Export-Csv ('C:\logs\security-log-{0}.csv' -f ([DateTime]::Now).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))
```

Then you can also simplify a bit:

```
Export-Csv ('security-log-{0:MM-dd-yyyy}.csv' -f Get-Date)
```

Comment: Hey Joey I have been playing with what you helped me with and your first line that I used `Export-Csv ('C:\logs\security-log-{0}.csv' -f ([DateTime]::Now).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))` needs an input, I am trying to write this script to be completly automated and to run the same time every week.  Am I dong something wrong?

Comment: Well, you can only export data. If you have no data to begin with, what would you actually export? PowerShell is pipeline-based. Export-Csv is a cmdlet that often stands at the end of a pipeline. It gets data as input and writes them along with their properties to a CSV file, e.g. `Get-ChildItem | Export-Csv files.csv`. The code as it stands here cannot work as is; I was assuming it was only part of the pipeline.