# Powershell logging process

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement for an audit to collect all Security logs weekly, when I arrived at my new job the current Sys Admin would manually log onto each machine and grab the logs save them and store them, I knew there was a better way (we had 50+ machines) I went along with it for a little while because I was the new guy but I talked to my manager about automating it and he thought it was a great idea.  So I have been working on a Power shell scrip to do this.  Here is what I have so far.

I need the script to pull from either a hostname or a name list I am attempting this here.

```
$computers = get-content C:\MyScripts\MachineNames.txt
foreach-object ($computer in $computers)
{
```

Here I am pulling the last 7 days and only the security logs of failed log on attempts.

```
$Date = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-7)
$Date.tostring("MM-dd-yyyy"), $env:Computername
Get-EventLog "Security" -After $Date 
| Where -FilterScript {$_.EventID -eq 4624 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[4].Length -gt 10 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[5] -notlike "*$"} `
| foreach-Object 
$row = "" | Select UserName, LoginTime
$row.UserName = $_.ReplacementStrings[5]
$row.LoginTime = $_.TimeGenerated
$row # this will put the current row to the pipeline
```

And now the part I have been really struggling with, I am looking for this to save the file in the directory I tell it to with the name of: Security-Log-dd-mm-yy.  This is what I have

```
Export-Csv ('C:\logs\security-log-{0}.csv' -f ([DateTime]::Now).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))
```

When I run the script like this at this point it asks for me to InputObject.

```
cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject:
```

What is the problem with the script that it isn't writing the data to the file, but instead is prompting for InputObject?

Comment: We tried to help you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188496/file-location-for-csv-file) already.  Please remember you can edit and/or add to your original question, instead of asking the same question in multiple threads and ways.  ;)

Comment: When you ask how to "do something better," that is considered vague and off-topic.  Your question should be pointedly asking how to get the data written to the file, because it isn't working and is prompting you for InputObject.

Comment: Thank you I am continuing to learn posting here, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't pipe anything to the `Export-Csv` cmdlet. You probably want to do something like this:

```
Get-EventLog "Security" -After $Date `
| Where -FilterScript {$_.EventID -eq 4624 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[4].Length -gt 10 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[5] -notlike "*$"} `
| foreach-Object {
    $row = "" | Select UserName, LoginTime
    $row.UserName = $_.ReplacementStrings[5]
    $row.LoginTime = $_.TimeGenerated
    $row # this will put the current row to the pipeline 
} | Export-Csv ('C:\logs\security-log-{0}.csv' -f ([DateTime]::Now).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))
```